# android :-Alarm manager not working

Tags: android, android-alarms

In my code alarm manger is not working.Rest of my application is working well.Please see my code.

```
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidAlarmService.class);
   myIntent.putExtra("class", "home");
   PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,myIntent, 0);
   AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
   alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),6000,pendingIntent);
```

and my android AlarmService class:-

```
public class AndroidAlarmService extends BroadcastReceiver implements URLs{
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     System.out.println("BroadCast\n");
     String name=intent.getStringExtra("class");
     if(name.equals("home")){

    Intent homeIn=new Intent(context,Home.class);
    context.startActivity(homeIn);
     }

}
}
```

in manifest I have done this;

```
 <receiver android:name=".AndroidAlarmService" android:enabled="true" >
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE"></action>
      </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

Why its not working??

Comment: did you add permission in your manifest xml. It Requires the READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

Comment: yes above the application tag....

Comment: It should not be above the application tag, but encapsulated in the tag.... Something like `<application ..... <receiver put your data here></receiver></application>`

Comment: I noticed another problem. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the answer.I made following changes:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AndroidAlarmService.class);
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,myIntent, 0);
```

In my AndroidAlarmService class:

```
Intent homeIn=new Intent(context,Home.class);
homeIn.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(homeIn);
```

Comment: it's working but can you tell me after force stop application it's not working so can you found any solution for it

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem until I found that I had put my Broadcast Receiver on a different package, not the general.

Simply changed:

```
<receiver android:name=".AndroidAlarmService" android:enabled="true" >
```

for:

```
<receiver android:name="com.MyCompany.MyPackage.AndroidAlarmService" android:enabled="true" >
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried changing the

```
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),6000,pendingIntent);
```

Have you tried changing the 6000 to something else? It seems like you have everything else correct.

EDIT:

Make sure you have the Read_phone_state permission in your manifest.

Comment: wht is the problem with 6000?? Does it mean 6 seconds??